# how can i extract all .zip links from a website?

Tags: linux, download, links

is there a tool to extract all `.zip` links from a website and save them to `.txt` file. I am using Linux mint.
I want all `.zip` links from this website:

```
http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/
```

Comment: Can you point the way to such a link? It is't obvious to me how to find one.

Comment: Is the link crap? Seems like as it does not contain .zip links, so your question should be minus one.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution although it's not perfect and requires you to have `curl` and `perl` installed, both should be already with Linux Mint, although my solution does include a Perl module I wrote that is available on CPAN. Again `cpan` should be available and installed on Linux Mint already, you might just have to configure it if you haven't already.

For the module *App::ExtractLinks*, you can install it like this:

```
$ cpan App::ExtractLinks
```

As long as your Perl setup is correct and any CPAN modules are visible in your path, you should now be able to run `extract-links` in your terminal. If you do that without piping anything in, you won't see anything because it just expects a stream of HTML, and it outputs to standard out (prints to your terminal) any URLs that appear in `href=""` or `src=""` attributes, so it's really simple, but by combining it with some things in the terminal we can nearly achieve what you asked.

If you save the following bash script to a file, and either give it executable permissions `chmod 755` or run it like this `bash filename`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read url
do
    while read id
    do
        curl -s -I "http://files.all-free-download.com/free_download_graphic_$id.html" | perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ && print "$1\n"'
    done < <(curl -s "$url" | extract-links | grep "_download" | grep -Eo '[0-9]*')
done < <(curl -s http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/ | extract-links | grep "\/download\/")
```

Now let me try and explain it line by line.

Firstly we pipe the output of the following command to a `while read` loop.

```
curl -s http://all-free-download.com/free-photos/ | extract-links | grep "\/download\/")
```

This gets the HTML from the URL you supplied, pipes the output stream to `extract-links`, (the `-s` argument to `curl` just means `curl` silently does this) which then displays all links found in the page. We then take this list of links and only look for the ones that have `/download/` in them, this is what the `grep` command is doing. This isn't a general solution of course, I had to have a look at the HTML source of the site you supplied and figured out their URL logic.

After we get only links with `/download/` in them we pass only them to the `while read` loop, which takes each one at a time and assigns the link to a variable `$url`. Next we do a similar operation again:

```
curl -s "$url" | extract-links | grep "_download" | grep -Eo '[0-9]*'
```

This runs the same thing we already did but over this particular link, this time filtering for any link that has `_download` in it, and then only takes the numbers from the link. This is again me figuring out the scheme they have to used to arrange links and downloads.

Let me just say at this point, that the reason this is quite involved is because there isn't any direct links to `.zip` files anywhere on the site, the `.zip` downloads commence after a HTTP redirect when you navigate to certain pages. Which brings me to the last section:

```
curl -s -I "http://files.all-free-download.com/free_download_graphic_$id.html" | perl -n -e '/^Location: (.*)$/ && print "$1\n"'
```

This is taking only the numbers from the links we retrieved in the previous step, again pipes them into a `while read` loop, assigns each one as variable `$id` and again we used `curl` this time with the `-I` option, which only retrieves the headers (instead of downloading the file), each page at this point then does a redirect which then points to the zip file itself. We run the output of `curl` via an inline `perl` script which is just a regex to get the `Location` HTTP header, which is the one that specifies which file to redirect to.

So finally all you have to do is:

```
bash my_script.sh > links.txt
```

**Edit**

One caveat is that repeated links may possibly appear, just based on me testing with this site you have mentioned, so bear that in mind.

And obviously this isn't a very efficient operation, but then again it is automated and there isn't necessarily any other way of getting at the data you want without having some admin access to the site.

Comment: sir, your code is just perfect but it stops after some time after 100-150 links, how can i upgrade this code to get all links or maybe use this code on different websites? please replay to me nobody i willing to help me